# Android "ClassNotFound" error report without many details - how do you proceed

Tags: android

I uploaded an Android app on Google Play Store, on the Beta track, and after a few days without errors I got this crash report. It says "ClassNotFoundException" but it doesn't say what class was not found... if you have encountered this situation before, can you advise me on where to look for the source of this bug? Thanks!

```
Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) (a7y18lte), Android 9
Report 2 of 2

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3581)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1803)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3574)
```

Comment: is you app multidex enabled?

Comment: It is not, I'll look into this now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem related to `multidex` with `Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) (a7y18lte), Android 9` device

Error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
```

So, try enabling `multidex`

```
defaultConfig {
 ...
 // Enabling multidex support.
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Gradle Dependency

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I'll look into it, but can I ask this: if this is the problem, shouldn't the app crash every time? In my case it runs fine on all the devices I've tested it, and also on all beta users -- only a single beta user seem to have this problem.
So, is it possible that not enabling multidex can cause a crash only SOME of the time, on rare cases?